# Create static library in Xcode for different architectures

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have an .h and .cpp file for iOS (ARMv8-a) and another .h and .cpp file for iPhone simulator (x86_64). I need to include them in an Xcode project.

How should I do that? Do I need to create another project/target for those files?

Thanks